# Getting an error in Reactjs. It says Unhandled Rejection (TypeError). But I already told it what to do if user types invalid name in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web-development-server

Just wanted to know if theres anyway I can get of `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError)`. I already put an if else statement that tells it to render one or the other. Either the result, or the message saying input valid country. I already looked over the web for a while. Please let me know. Thanks. Here is my code and picture of error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from "./navbar";
import axios from "axios";
import Accordion from './accordion';
import Accordions from './accordion';
import ErrorBoundary from "./Carousel";


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: undefined,
      name: undefined,
      nativeName:undefined,
      callingCodes: undefined,
      capital: undefined, 
      currencies:undefined,
      languages: undefined,
      region:undefined,
      population:undefined,
      alpha3Code:undefined,
      isSearched: false,
      subregion: undefined,
      error: ""
    }
  }


  getCity = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.cityname.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${city}?fullText=true`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
      flag: data[0].flag,
      name: data[0].name,
      nativeName: data[0].nativeName,
      alpha3Code: data[0].alpha3Code,
      callingCodes: data[0].callingCodes,
      capital: data[0].capital,
      currencies: data[0].currencies[0].name,
      languages: data[0].languages[0].name,
      region: data[0].region,
      population: data[0].population,
      subregion:data[0].subregion
    });
}

toggleSearch = () => {
  this.setState({
    isSearched: true
  })
}



  render() {
    let search;
    if(this.state.isSearched) {
      search = 
      <div className="content-1">
      <div className="marginbottom">
        <img className="flags" src={this.state.flag}/>
          <h2><span className="bold">Name:</span> {this.state.name}</h2>
          <div><span className="bold">Native Name:</span> {this.state.nativeName}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Abbreviation:</span> {this.state.alpha3Code}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Calling Code:</span> {this.state.callingCodes}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Capital: </span>{this.state.capital}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Currencies:</span> {this.state.currencies}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Language:</span> {this.state.languages}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Region: </span>{this.state.region}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Population:</span> {this.state.population}</div>
        </div>
        <Accordions name={this.state.name} population={this.state.population} subregion={this.state.subregion}/>
      </div>
    } else {
      search=<p>Enter a valid country name</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Globe Search</h1>
          <h5>Search For Cities Around the Globe</h5>
        </header>
      <div class="content">
      <NavBar/>
      <form
         onSubmit={this.getCity}   >
            <input
               placeholder="Enter Country"
               type="text"
               name="cityname"/>
            <button onClick={this.toggleSearch} className="btn btn-success m-2">Search</button>
          </form>
          <div>
        <div>{search}</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you wrap your entire `getCity` logic in a `try`/`catch` and log out the error, what does it say?

Comment: Saids the following:
{status: 404, message: "Not Found"}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined
    at _callee$ (App.js:40)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:288)
    at Generator.prototype.(:3000/anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:494:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:

Comment: Maybe I'm off on this, but your button doesn't submit so `this.getCity` is never called and the state never gets set aside from `isSearched` being set to `true` when the button is clicked. Because `isSearched` is changed to `true` but the rest of the state remains undefined, on the re-render, `this.state.flag` and others are still undefined, so the system returns an error.

Comment: What is your React version ?

Comment: @Emidomenge React16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you submit empty value or invalid place you will get the error as you will try to get an unknown url. so you can check if city value is empty or not and also check the response from the api and update state accordingly

```
 getCity = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.cityname.value;
    // check if input field is empty or not
    if(city) {
      const api_call = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${city}?fullText=true`);
      const data = await api_call.json();
      console.log(data);
      // check if value entered in input is valid 
      // so check api returns a valid response or not
      if(data && !data.status) {
        this.setState({
        isSearched: true,
        flag: data[0].flag,
        name: data[0].name,
        nativeName: data[0].nativeName,
        alpha3Code: data[0].alpha3Code,
        callingCodes: data[0].callingCodes,
        capital: data[0].capital,
        currencies: data[0].currencies[0].name,
        languages: data[0].languages[0].name,
        region: data[0].region,
        population: data[0].population,
        subregion:data[0].subregion
       });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          isSearched:false
        })
      }   
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isSearched:false
      })
    }    
  }
```

And also change the button to `type="submit"`

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-success m-2">Search</button>
```

No need of `toggleSearch` method

Everthing will work fine

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your button to a submit type `<button type="submit" ...>` so `this.getCity` is called. If you need `isSearched`, call it from `this.getCity` or make a new submit function `handleSearch()` and put `this.toggleSearch()` and `this.getCity()` inside it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from "./navbar";
import axios from "axios";
import Accordion from './accordion';
import Accordions from './accordion';
import ErrorBoundary from "./Carousel";


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: undefined,
      name: undefined,
      nativeName:undefined,
      callingCodes: undefined,
      capital: undefined, 
      currencies:undefined,
      languages: undefined,
      region:undefined,
      population:undefined,
      alpha3Code:undefined,
      isSearched: false,
      subregion: undefined,
      error: ""
    }
  }


  getCity = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Call toggleSearch somewhere in here if you really need it
    this.toggleSearch();

    const city = e.target.elements.cityname.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${city}?fullText=true`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
      flag: data[0].flag,
      name: data[0].name,
      nativeName: data[0].nativeName,
      alpha3Code: data[0].alpha3Code,
      callingCodes: data[0].callingCodes,
      capital: data[0].capital,
      currencies: data[0].currencies[0].name,
      languages: data[0].languages[0].name,
      region: data[0].region,
      population: data[0].population,
      subregion:data[0].subregion
    });
}

toggleSearch = () => {
  this.setState({
    isSearched: true
  })
}



  render() {
    let search;
    if(this.state.isSearched) {
      search = 
      <div className="content-1">
      <div className="marginbottom">
        <img className="flags" src={this.state.flag}/>
          <h2><span className="bold">Name:</span> {this.state.name}</h2>
          <div><span className="bold">Native Name:</span> {this.state.nativeName}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Abbreviation:</span> {this.state.alpha3Code}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Calling Code:</span> {this.state.callingCodes}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Capital: </span>{this.state.capital}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Currencies:</span> {this.state.currencies}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Language:</span> {this.state.languages}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Region: </span>{this.state.region}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Population:</span> {this.state.population}</div>
        </div>
        <Accordions name={this.state.name} population={this.state.population} subregion={this.state.subregion}/>
      </div>
    } else {
      search=<p>Enter a valid country name</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Globe Search</h1>
          <h5>Search For Cities Around the Globe</h5>
        </header>
      <div class="content">
      <NavBar/>
      <form
         onSubmit={this.getCity}   >
            <input
               placeholder="Enter Country"
               type="text"
               name="cityname"/>

            {/* Removed onClick and added type="submit" */}
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success m-2">Search</button>

          </form>
          <div>
        <div>{search}</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line

```
const city = e.target.elements.cityname.value;
```

doesn't receive an expected value. As a result, you're fetching an unknow url here:

```
const api_call = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${city}?fullText=true`);
```

Then everything below are undefined and you're getting such errors.

Comment: How do I get it to render a message like `please enter valid city` instead of it rendering the error page? Thanks!

Comment: @KennyQuach One solution will be to do an array containing all valid cities and then to check if the variable "city" match an element from your array

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: undefined,
      name: undefined,
      nativeName:undefined,
      callingCodes: undefined,
      capital: undefined, 
      currencies:undefined,
      languages: undefined,
      region:undefined,
      population:undefined,
      alpha3Code:undefined,
      isSearched: false,
      subregion: undefined,
      error: ""
    }
  }


  getCity = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.cityname.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${city}?fullText=true`);
    api_call.json()
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        flag: data[0].flag,
        name: data[0].name,
        nativeName: data[0].nativeName,
        alpha3Code: data[0].alpha3Code,
        callingCodes: data[0].callingCodes,
        capital: data[0].capital,
        currencies: data[0].currencies[0].name,
        languages: data[0].languages[0].name,
        region: data[0].region,
        population: data[0].population,
        subregion:data[0].subregion,
        error: ''
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({error})
    })
}

toggleSearch = () => {
  this.setState({
    isSearched: true
  })
}



  render() {
    let search;
    if(this.state.isSearched && this.state.error === '') {
      search = 
      <div className="content-1">
      <div className="marginbottom">
        <img className="flags" src={this.state.flag}/>
          <h2><span className="bold">Name:</span> {this.state.name}</h2>
          <div><span className="bold">Native Name:</span> {this.state.nativeName}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Abbreviation:</span> {this.state.alpha3Code}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Calling Code:</span> {this.state.callingCodes}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Capital: </span>{this.state.capital}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Currencies:</span> {this.state.currencies}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Language:</span> {this.state.languages}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Region: </span>{this.state.region}</div>
          <div><span className="bold">Population:</span> {this.state.population}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    } else {
      search=<p>Enter a valid country name</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Globe Search</h1>
          <h5>Search For Cities Around the Globe</h5>
        </header>
      <div class="content">
      <form
         onSubmit={this.getCity}   >
            <input
               placeholder="Enter Country"
               type="text"
               name="cityname"/>
            <button onClick={this.toggleSearch} className="btn btn-success m-2">Search</button>
          </form>
          <div>
        <div>{search}</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```